# How to Hide a Form using the .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, hide

I'm working on a smart device with installed Windows Mobile 6.1. I need to completely hide my application (a `Form`), but i'm not able to do this. I tried to call the `Form.Hide` method, but it does not have any effects, the form is still open, visible and maximized. I tried also to follow [this post](http://christian-helle.blogspot.it/2007/06/programmatically-minimize-application.html):

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Hide();
}

public new void Hide()
{
    const int SW_MINIMIZED = 6;

    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    ControlBox = true;
    MinimizeBox = true;
    MaximizeBox = true;

    // Since there is no WindowState.Minimize, we have to P/Invoke ShowWindow
    ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
}
```

But without any effects (again).
What is the proper way to do this work?

Comment: You cannot hide a window that's not visible yet.  Instead set the form's WindowState property to FormWindowState.Minimized.  Or just don't call Show() until you actually want it to be visible.

Comment: If you want to "hide" the app, why do you have a Form in the first place?

Comment: @ctacke What have I to use in place of my From?

Comment: Well a standard app that just has a `static void Main` entry point would provide an app with no Form.  It could have a loop in it, be multi-threaded or whatever.  If you need to process Windows messages (you've given no indication one way or the other) you could create your own message pump as well.  There are loads of options.

Comment: The problem with dotnet smartdevice forms is, that using FormState in the Forms constructor has no effect. As the contructor is called, you cannot alter the formstate, you have to use a schedule to set the formstate to Minimized. Or, better, do not use a form at all. See also some nice windows states at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/11/07/mobile-development-move-your-form/

Comment: @ctacke You're right, please write your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application doesn't need to have a call to `Application.Run` (which requires a Form in the Compact Framework) to operate.  If your app doesn't need a UI, don't create a Form.  You can create a state loop, multithread and just about anything else from the `Main` entry point without a Form just fine.  If you need to process Windows messages, you can always create your own message pump by calling `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` yourself.